# jqGrid checkbox events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, checkbox

I have a jqGrid it has a checkbox in the rows.  I need to be able to change the value depending of if it is being checked or unchecked.  Using this in the $(document).ready block does not work.  I have tried multiple solutions that I have found on the forum and nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions?

```
 $('#glReportCodesGrid').children("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    var y = $(this).val();
    if (y == 'false') {
        $(this).val('true');
    }
    else { $(this).val('false'); }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following selector to find the checkboxes:

```
jQuery(".jqgrow td input", "#glReportCodesGrid").click(function () {
```

You would need to call the above from one of the grid events that is triggered after the grid is initialized.

Alternatively, you can use [jQuery.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to dynamically bind the event handler when the elements are created:

```
jQuery(document).delegate(
    '#glReportCodesGrid .jqgrow td input', 
    'click', 
    function () { ... });
```

The question [jqgrid-with-an-editable-checkbox-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928919/jqgrid-with-an-editable-checkbox-column/2782019#2782019) has some related information that you may find helpful.